# Position image without autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I hope this question makes sense.

I have 2 images in my viewcontroller. One is for a background and the second I need to move around on top of that image freely. I am using autolayout for the background image, but when I test on different devices the second image is not in the proper place because I am not using the autolayout on it and therefore it does not move correctly.

How can I move the image to be in the proper place. Is there some way to set it properly in code. I guess I mean how could I set the autolayout in code since this image will have many positions it needs to move to.

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: I have not tried to do it in code yet. I am currently searching for how to do it via code. I need to be able to set the x and y position of the second image.

Comment: can you show some UI what type of the OP you expect

Comment: Sure let me try to get some screen grabs